# Cordova File Transfer download ENOENT error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I have to manage and update an old Cordova project, that used File Transfer Plugin for Android platform.

The download functionality is not working and i get this error:

> exception: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.name/files/img.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

My download function is:

```
function downloadFile(remotepath,localpath,filename,r){
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(remotepath+filename);  // https://example.com/download/img.jpg
    var local = localpath+filename;            // /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.name/files/img.jpg
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        local,
        function(entry) {
            entry.getMetadata((metaData) => {
              console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
              r(metaData.size);
            });
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }
```

It seems working only if target file already exists, otherwise I get ENOENT 'no such file or directory' error.
Permissions for read and write storage are granted.

Comment: Have you checked if that files directory already exists? You do not need any permission for that path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error was that the target folder didn't exist, and I had to create it before download the file. It' strange since with a previuos version of this plugin I hadn't to be worried about the path and folders were created automatically.